# Any efficient way to build up regression model on panel data?

Tags: python, regression, panel-data

I have two dimensional data including frequent crime type in certain regions and corresponding house prices along the year. I want to understand possible association between crime frequency in certain regions and house price fluctuation. Initially I tried to use linear regression to do that, but it didn't work well. Now I want to try PCA analysis on my data, but it is still not efficient to me to grab meaningful results. How can I perform efficient PCA analysis on panel data for the purpose of doing regression? any efficient workaround to make this happen? thanks

**data** :

because my data is bit long in terms of dimension, it is bit difficult to make reproducible example here, so let's see how panel data looks like:

[image]
[image]

here is safest cloud link that you can browse input panel data: [example data snippet](https://filebin.net/ml0sjn455gr8pvh3).

**update: my attempt**:

since @ flyingmeatball pointed out that using PCA is not a good idea, I tried simple linear regression but it didn't help me to capture the relation between crime frequencies and house price. here is what I did:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import re
import urllib
import pandas as pd

# download data from cloud
u = "https://filebin.net/ml0sjn455gr8pvh3/crime_realEstate?t=7dkm15wq"
crime_realEstate = urllib.request.urlretrieve (u, "Ktest.csv")

# or just manually download data first and read
crime_realEstate = pd.read_csv('crime_realEstate.csv')
cols_2012 = crime_realEstate.filter(regex='_2012').columns
crime_realEstate['Area_Name']=crime_realEstate['Area_Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(' ', '_', str(x)))
regDF_2012 = crime_realEstate[cols_2012]
regDF_2012 = regDF_2012.assign(community_code=crime_finalDF['community_area'])
regDF_2012.dropna(inplace=True)
X_feats = regDF_2012.drop(['Avg_Price_2012'], axis=1)
y_label = regDF_2012['Avg_Price_2012'].values

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = poly.fit_transform(X_feats)
y= sc_y.fit_transform(y_label.reshape(-1,1)).flatten()
X = log(X)
y = log(y)
regModel = LinearRegression()
regModel.fit(X, y)
```

above code doesn't help me because I want to see which features contributed to house price fluctuation along the year. Any thoughts on how to make this happen?

**goal**:

what I am trying to achieve is to build model that explain the dynamics between crime frequency in certain regions and respective house price fluctuation. Any efficient workaround to make this happen?

**update**:

if PCA is not good idea, then any possible regression model that can capture the relation between crime frequencies in certain community area and house price fluctuation? any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple thoughts:

1) Please post complete code. I don't see where crime_realEstate is defined anywhere. If you leave out the line where you read in your data to that variable, it makes it really hard to reproduce your error, and you're less likely to get help. Also, you should organize all of your import statements so they are at the top of your code. It isn't really a function thing, more of a convention that everyone expects and makes it easier to read.

2) When you reference panel data, are you really talking about a pandas DataFrame? That is sort of the "typical" way to store this kind of stuff for analysis. You may want to get in the habit of referring to data as dataframes so it's clearer to your audience. You should also post the full error traceback so we can see what line of code is bombing exactly.

3) I think you may be misunderstanding PCA, or at least what it is for. PCA (principle component analysis) is a data transformation method, where you are capturing variation in data that is across multiple variables and restating that data as fewer components that capture the same amount (or less, depending on how many components you keep) of variability. Once you run PCA, you won't be able to see which features are contributing to crime, because they will be replaced by totally new components. If it is important to identify the features that are correlated with crime, then PCA is a bad idea.

Please fix items above.

**EDIT**

I'm not saying PCA is *wrong*, I'm just saying that the question you asked above ("how do I apply PCA and why is my code bombing"), isn't really the right question. PCA should be used if you think that you have many correlated variables that need to be reduced to a lower level of dimensionality. I wouldn't start there though - see what kind of accuracy you can get without doing that. You've now reformulated to a much broader question of "how do I make a predictive model for this data, preferably using a regression?", which should probably go to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ instead, but I'll give you a starting point of how I would approach coding that solution.

First - PCA is probably not the ideal starting point because from just looking at the data/columns, your problem isn't dimensionality. You basically have 10 different crimes over 5 years. You also only have 58 different rows...or is that just the sample data? Also, your data is a bit weird - you have the same prices for multiple rows, but the crimes differ. I can't tell if it's just because you're posting sample data. If this is indeed the full dataset, stop your analysis now and get more data/go do something else.

I made some executive decisions about how I would approach the problem. All of these are just for demonstration purposes of how to code regression. I summed crime across all years (you maybe want average? Highest? Change in? Those are all design decisions for you). My metric was Change in Price From 2012-2016, the timeframe you have crime data. I normalized crime counts by type of crime. Didn't scale the target variable.

Here's how I would start:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import pandas as pd

# Load data
filePath = 'L:\\crime_realEstate.txt'
crime_df = pd.read_csv(filePath, sep = '\t').drop(['Unnamed: 0','community_area'],axis = 1)

#calculate price change between 2016 and 2012 - same timeframe you have crime data
crime_df['price_change'] = crime_df['Avg_Price_2016'] - crime_df['Avg_Price_2012']
crime_df.drop(['Avg_Price_2012','Avg_Price_2013','Avg_Price_2014','Avg_Price_2015','Avg_Price_2016','Avg_Price_2017','Avg_Price_2018','Avg_Price_2019'],axis = 1,inplace = True)

#split years if they are data over time
crime_df.columns =  pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x.split('_20')[1] if '_20' in x else x ,x.split('_20')[0]) for x in crime_df.columns])
#sum across years for crimeFields
crime_df = crime_df.groupby(level=[1],axis = 1).sum(axis = 1)

#split out tgt var
price_growth = crime_df['price_change']

#create dummy variable from area name
dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(crime_df['Area_Name'])


crime_df.drop(['Area_Name','price_change'],axis = 1,inplace = True)

#scales crime variables
scaler = StandardScaler()
crime_df[crime_df.columns] = scaler.fit_transform(crime_df)

crime_df = pd.merge(crime_df,dummy_df,left_index = True, right_index = True)

regModel = LinearRegression()

#split to training testing
train_df = crime_df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=200)
test_df = crime_df.drop(train_df.index)

regModel.fit(train_df, price_growth[train_df.index])

#R2 
r2_score(price_growth.drop(train_df.index),regModel.predict(test_df))
0.7355837132941521
```

Simpler answer to your analysis: wherever the white people live in Chicago, the property is expensive.

Comment: @ flyingmeatball I fixed the problem. if PCA is worse, then what should I do? how can I build model which capture the relation between crime frequencies in certain area and house price fluctuation? Could you elaborate your point with possible coding exercise? Thank you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22850699)

Comment: @ Zoe I update my post with clear specification and clean coding part, could you point me out how to solve my question? any idea?

Comment: @zoe The critique/clarification wasn't going to be possible in <600 characters. I thought it better to give him constructive feedback that will be helpful to him, rather than adhere to arbitrary character limits. Now that he's edited his question, I can edit my response to a more meaningful answer. Let's not let process get in the way from our ultimate goal (helping him understand how to apply PCA).

Comment: @flyingmeatball so? You can still post several comments. And the 600 char limit is NOT an excuse to abuse the answer section. Also, there's nothing preventing you from posting several comments in a row. Please re-read [answer] and [when to comment](/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @Dan just to make it clear - the comment wasn't aimed at you. Also, for the @ mention to work, there can't be a space between the @ and the username (hence why I'm not replying until now, I didn't get notified until OP of the answer pinged me)

Comment: @Zoe thank you for your community help, I'll pay attention when I asked the question also.

Comment: @flyingmeatball I tried to render scatter plot for your solution, I didn't get better one. How can I transform data that you get for seeing the plot? could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your data. Here's my 2 cents on few preprocessing steps:

1. You need to rearrange it, such that Y is Price_For_Area_Year. e.g. your first record transforms into following:

[image]

2. 1 hot encode the area/area_code
3. Impute missing values using some standard method
4. take care of multicollinearity using pca etc. The independent variables have high correlation.

I think you should get some meaningful linear correlation. If not, try transforming some of the variables into ranks. Do share how that works out.

Comment: can you elaborate your point with sketch coding solution instead?